# Как фильтровать заказы по значению свойства заказов?

Tags: битрикс

Как фильтровать заказы по значению свойства заказов в методе `\Bitrix\Sale\Order::getList`
Например, есть заказ и у него есть свойство `DAY` (день) тип строка, и значение свойства `Fr` (пятница) свойство относится к группе служебные 
http://joxi.ru/Y2LpQ8Df7DQ4N2

Так выводится это свойство в заказе: http://joxi.ru/eAO0W56F9lpWOr

В документации https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_d7/bitrix/sale/technique/orders.php
есть пример, как я понимаю, именно по мой задаче: http://joxi.ru/nAyLJe6Sgej6p2

На основе примера написал код:

```
   $dbRes = \Bitrix\Sale\Order::getList([
   'select' => [
       "ID",
   ],
   'filter' => [
    'USER_ID' => $USER->GetID(),
       '=PROPERTY_VAL.CODE' => 'DAY',
       '=PROPERTY_VAL.VALUE' => 'Fr',
   ]

]);

while ($order = $dbRes->fetch())
{
   var_dump($order);
}
```

Но код не работает выводится ошибка Unknown field definition `PROPERTY_VAL` (PROPERTY_VAL.CODE)

Answer (score 0):

В вашем же вопросе и ответ. Последняя картинка. Вы почему в своем запросе не используете runtime? Понятно, что свойства у Вас нету, вы его не добавили.

Добавьте runtime в запрос